# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol when building DLL project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

Not sure what is wrong with my Visual Studio 2013 code, but when building it throws this error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct
>   RestClient::response __cdecl RestClient::get(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &)"
>   (?get@RestClient@@SA?AUresponse@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: long __stdcall
>   CSHost::SendToRest(wchar_t *,wchar_t *,wchar_t *)"
>   (?SendToRest@CSHost@@QAGJPA_W00@Z)    C:\Users\Projects\SHost.obj ProjectName

I'm trying to use https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp in a DLL project.

What could be the possible cause of this error?

Comment: I need to re-open this to put the answer since I was able to fix the issue